# C# ASP.NET Page Leaving event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was looking for an event that would fire or a way to tell if the user was leaving a page. Either to navigate to another page or closing the page alltogether. Is this possible through the events that fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in ASP.NET per se.

You will have to write some front-end javascript to do this using something like `window.onbeforeunload()`.  Then you'd have to make an AJAX call to tell your back-end that this event is happening.   This isn't foolproof, of course.  A browser crash or a forced "quit" would not fire this event.

Comment: @Nic: Because your web application can't rely on this behavior, consider designing the application to work without it.

Comment: Thank you Dave! I will follow-up later with a sample for people that are interested. Thank you again for the suggestion Dave.

Comment: @Jeff Mattfield; Yes I would agree with you however you cannot always adopt such ridged mindsets in the real world of development. Sometimes we are put into positions where we inherit an application and said application wasn't arch with this methodology and all you are trying to do is do some cleanup to get you buy till you can invest that time.

Answer (score 0):

Not through server-side events. Detecting page-leaving requires JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side, you can use `onunload()` (or `onbeforeunload()` to give an "are you sure" that they will be grateful for if it meant they stopped accidentally closing something after writing a long stackoverlow.com post, but will annoy users in most cases).

Server-side, you can't really, though you could have the onunload do something to signal to the server.

As a rule though, this indicates you are treating the web as stateful, rather than stateless. Stateless designs work better with stateless protocols like the web's; the more your application treats each request as unique and independent of previous requests (though of course, just what that request is will depend on how the client dealt with the previous request) the more scalable and reliable your application.