# Asp.net control the closure of a web page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an Asp.net WebForm with this simple code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="NetmedWeb.Test" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function quit() { event.returnValue = "Confirm?" }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onbeforeunload="quit(); return 'Sure?';">
        <div>
            Try to close me !!!
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</asp:Content>
```

The script works if I try to close the browser or if I close a page and even if I change the page, all is well.
However, I would like the script to activate only in some situations, not always, on the C # code side.
For example:

```
private void TestScript()
{
    if (mycondition)
    {
        Activate script
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Such as?

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to make an AJAX call to tell your back-end that this event is happening.
check this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428398/2941659

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a variable inside the `<body>` tag.

```
<body onbeforeunload="<%= unload %>">
```

And then set it to the script when needed from code behind

```
public string unload = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        unload = "quit(); return 'Sure?';";
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you say, but it doesn't ask me anything, it just closes.

Comment: There is no difference between writing it yourself or having a variable write it to the html. But you do have nested `<hml>` and `<head>` tags, that could cause issues.

Comment: This is my simple code (I can't insert it formatted):

       <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="NetmedWeb.test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="<%= unload %>">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>